# Вывод статьи не по id, а по title в адресной строке

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Как сделать так чтобы при переходе на статью было /page/title, вместо /page/id.

И если есть возможность, добавить второй вариант, где используются два и более значения, например /page/title&name...

Также в идеале закодировать ссылку в base64

файл url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('page/<id>/', post, name='sub-detail'),
]
```

файл models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    overview = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })
```

файл views.py

```
def post(request, id):
    return render(request, 'post.html', {})
```

Comment: Почитайте про slug

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Спасибо за подсказку, попробую реализовать=)

Comment: А еще изучите CBV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты хочешь конкретно генерировать url от названия статьи (поля title), то придётся изучить генерацию slugify.
Если хочешь проще, то в моделях добавь поле:

`slug = models.SlugField("Постоянная ссылка", max_length = 50, blank=True, unique=True)`

Также было бы круто определить метод, возвращающий ссылку на статью. Код ниже это делает, добавь его в models.py в свой класс Post (не забудь подключить reverse в верхней части код (не в классе Post))

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.slug is None:
            return reverse('имя ссылки на персональную страницу из файла urls.py', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
        return reverse('имя ссылки на персональную страницу из файла urls.py', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Идём дальше. Тебе нужно будет ловить эти ссылки в файле urls.py. Реализуй примерно так (обрати внимание, что пусть со слагом стоит выше пути с идентефикатором):

```
path('post/<str:slug>/', имя класса(или фукции) обработчика, name='post-detail_url')
path('post/<int:pk>/', имя класса(или фукции) обработчика, name='post-detail_url')
```

В шаблонах для генерации ссылок используй следущий код:

```
{{ post.get_absolute_url }}
```

Comment: Привет, допустим получилось, а как ссылку конвертировать в base64. Например было /post/title1 стало /post/dGl0bGUx